# Multi gateway work with HAProxy and VPN?

Tags: haproxy, pfsense

We have a situation where we will have two physical router gateways on the network, each connected to its own ISP. Due to business requirements, we cannot merge the two WANs onto a single router, thus two routers must exist.

We want our remote users be able to VPN in, via either WAN/Router, and be able to access the internal-web-server. With the diagram below, I know that the remote user will need to have two separate VPN app/profile/account setup, one per WAN/Router and thats no problem.

Would the diagram below do what Im looking for? The general idea below is to setup a HAProxy, set all devices's default gateway to point to the HAProxy and have HAProxy handle the connections to the routers. Unfortunately I am quite new to this whole proxy thing and not sure if HAProxy would do what Im looking for.

Proposed Setup:
[image]

As a FYI, below shows what we have currently, all devices's gateway are pointing to Router Gateway 1. The problem is that when remote users VPN via WAN-XYZ, into Router Gateway 2, they cant seem to access the internal-web-server. To my understanding, this problem is due to the default gateway on the internal-web-server is set to Router Gateway 1.

Current Setup:
[image]

Addition notes Router 2 will be a pfSense router.

Comment: Not familiar with haproxy / load balancing, but my first thought about your scenario is that, what you need seems to be something like setting conntrack mark based on L2 source address, and setting fwmark (which will be matched by an ip rule) for corresponding replying traffics, and they should be set up directly on the server host. I have never actually deployed such "split routing" setup myself but I think it is possible with nftables on Linux (so no idea if your web server has Windows or BSD).

Comment: Not sure about a pfSense router, but with a decent router you should move the ISP routers out of your 'flat' network and put the router between them and your LAN. A decent router should be able to return traffic back the ISP where it originated from (for inbound connections) and provide some form of load balancing (for outbound connections). Policy-based routing based on protocol or on source IP address might also work well. All that should work without a proxy (which might be a major pain).

Comment: Btw, unless you can make your ISP routers perform *source* NAT for traffics from *the Internet*, I don't think a proxy makes sense / matters since ultimately it will need to "split route" the *replies* based on the source *MAC* address of the *original* traffics. The proxy can forward replies to corresponding routers only if the *destination IP* address of the replies can *indicate* the router they should go to, which is turn only the case if the ISP routers can be configured to perform that kind of quirky source NAT. (Besides, it's not scalable / realistic to masquerade for the Internet.)

Answer (score 0):

I just simulated you scenario / need with three VMs and two (independent) bridges on a VM host and formulated / tested a solution (which is what I mentioned in my comment) for it.

The VM host acts as the web server, and two of the VMs act as the routers, one of the VM act as a web client from "the Internet":

[image]

Configurations on the VM host (web server):

```
$ ip a show dev bridge1
4: bridge1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.254.3/24 scope global bridge1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::38f6:7bff:fe90:aabd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip a show dev bridge2
5: bridge2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1a:6f:58:86:72:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::186f:58ff:fe86:7255/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

(`bridge1` is used for simulating the LAN, and `bridge2` is used for simulating "the Internet", so the latter isn't assigned an IPv4 address.)

```
$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32765:  from all fwmark 0xb iif lo lookup 11
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

$ ip r show table main dev bridge1
10.10.10.0/24 via 192.168.254.1 
192.168.254.0/24 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.254.3 

$ ip r show table 11
10.10.10.0/24 via 192.168.254.2 dev bridge1
```

(Here `192.168.254.1` is assumed to be the "primary" default gateway. `iif lo` is a refinement that causes the rule to only be applied on traffics that originated from the host itself, in other words it is probably unnecessary unless the web server host is also acting as some sort of router.)

```
$ sudo nft list ruleset
table ip mangle {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority mangle; policy accept;
        ether saddr 52:54:00:bb:bb:bb ip saddr != 192.168.254.2 ct mark set 0x0000000b
    }

    chain output {
        type route hook output priority mangle; policy accept;
        ct mark 0x0000000b meta mark set ct mark
    }
}
```

(Apparently `type` must be `route` in the `hook output` chain for this to work. Also, traffics originated from the routers, unlike traffics originated from "the Internet", can be differentiated as per their source IP addresses, so `ip saddr != 192.168.254.2` is specified to indicate the fact; in reality it's probably an unnecessary refinement.)

Here's the `tcpdump` capture on the VM host / web server of the two `curl` run done on the web client VM:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -eni bridge1 tcp port 80
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on bridge1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
16:54:43.602105 52:54:00:aa:aa:aa > 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.10.10.3.33132 > 192.168.254.3.80: Flags [S], seq 2320058647, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3412464375 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:54:43.602185 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd > 52:54:00:aa:aa:aa, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.254.3.80 > 10.10.10.3.33132: Flags [S.], seq 3987984937, ack 2320058648, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3768307023 ecr 3412464375,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:54:43.603460 52:54:00:aa:aa:aa > 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.10.10.3.33132 > 192.168.254.3.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 3412464377 ecr 3768307023], length 0
16:54:43.604003 52:54:00:aa:aa:aa > 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 140: 10.10.10.3.33132 > 192.168.254.3.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:75, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 3412464377 ecr 3768307023], length 74: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
16:54:43.604054 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd > 52:54:00:aa:aa:aa, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 192.168.254.3.80 > 10.10.10.3.33132: Flags [.], ack 75, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3768307025 ecr 3412464377], length 0
16:54:43.604238 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd > 52:54:00:aa:aa:aa, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 329: 192.168.254.3.80 > 10.10.10.3.33132: Flags [P.], seq 1:264, ack 75, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3768307025 ecr 3412464377], length 263: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
16:54:43.604636 52:54:00:aa:aa:aa > 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.10.10.3.33132 > 192.168.254.3.80: Flags [.], ack 264, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3412464378 ecr 3768307025], length 0
16:54:43.605112 52:54:00:aa:aa:aa > 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.10.10.3.33132 > 192.168.254.3.80: Flags [F.], seq 75, ack 264, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3412464379 ecr 3768307025], length 0
16:54:43.605133 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd > 52:54:00:aa:aa:aa, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 192.168.254.3.80 > 10.10.10.3.33132: Flags [F.], seq 264, ack 76, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3768307026 ecr 3412464379], length 0
16:54:43.605270 52:54:00:aa:aa:aa > 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.10.10.3.33132 > 192.168.254.3.80: Flags [.], ack 265, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3412464379 ecr 3768307026], length 0

16:54:47.528893 52:54:00:bb:bb:bb > 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.10.10.3.49270 > 192.168.254.3.80: Flags [S], seq 1866708541, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1196345946 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:54:47.528977 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd > 52:54:00:bb:bb:bb, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.254.3.80 > 10.10.10.3.49270: Flags [S.], seq 1756841838, ack 1866708542, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3768310949 ecr 1196345946,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:54:47.530210 52:54:00:bb:bb:bb > 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.10.10.3.49270 > 192.168.254.3.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1196345947 ecr 3768310949], length 0
16:54:47.530535 52:54:00:bb:bb:bb > 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 140: 10.10.10.3.49270 > 192.168.254.3.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:75, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1196345948 ecr 3768310949], length 74: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
16:54:47.530588 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd > 52:54:00:bb:bb:bb, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 192.168.254.3.80 > 10.10.10.3.49270: Flags [.], ack 75, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3768310951 ecr 1196345948], length 0
16:54:47.530744 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd > 52:54:00:bb:bb:bb, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 329: 192.168.254.3.80 > 10.10.10.3.49270: Flags [P.], seq 1:264, ack 75, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3768310951 ecr 1196345948], length 263: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
16:54:47.531434 52:54:00:bb:bb:bb > 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.10.10.3.49270 > 192.168.254.3.80: Flags [.], ack 264, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 1196345949 ecr 3768310951], length 0
16:54:47.532994 52:54:00:bb:bb:bb > 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.10.10.3.49270 > 192.168.254.3.80: Flags [F.], seq 75, ack 264, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 1196345951 ecr 3768310951], length 0
16:54:47.533092 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd > 52:54:00:bb:bb:bb, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 192.168.254.3.80 > 10.10.10.3.49270: Flags [F.], seq 264, ack 76, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3768310954 ecr 1196345951], length 0
16:54:47.533925 52:54:00:bb:bb:bb > 3a:f6:7b:90:aa:bd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.10.10.3.49270 > 192.168.254.3.80: Flags [.], ack 265, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 1196345951 ecr 3768310954], length 0
^C
20 packets captured
20 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

As you can see, the destination MAC addresses of the replies match with the source MAC addresses of the corresponding original traffics, which means they were being send to the router that the respective original traffics came from, *even when the IP addresses are identical*. (Also, as shown in the screenshot, both run successfully fetched the target web page.)

---

***Rationale of the nftable ruleset***

The `ct mark` *setting* in the `hook input` chain will cause the mark to be set for all traffics of the same "connection". (I am not / cannot really go deep into that but if you want to know more about it, research about "conntrack".) Therefore, in the `hook output` chain you can "select" the corresponding replies with the `ct mark` *matching*, and perform `meta mark set ct mark` on them, which means to set a `meta mark` on the replies of the same value as the `ct mark` (i.e. `0xb`, which is an arbitrary value btw). (You can set it to a different value instead too.)

`meta mark` corresponds to `fwmark` in the ip rule and therefore, an extra route table (`11` in the example, which is also an arbitrary value) will be looked up for traffics with `meta mark` that is equal to the `fwmark` in the rule, *before* (because of the lower priority value) the route table `main` is looked up.

Since in route table `11` there's a route for `10.10.10.0/24` with a different nexthop (i.e. `via`) from the one in route table `main`, the selected replies will be sent to the "correct" router. (No further lookup is performed when there's a route that "covers" the destination address.)

Although `10.10.10.0/24` is used instead of `default` a.k.a. `0.0.0.0/0` and the "routers" are connected to the same bridge along side the web client host to simulate the real Internet, it shouldn't prevent the drill from working in the real situation.

Comment: Similar drill can probably be deployed with an intermediate router host, in which case the ct and meta mark setting rules should be used with a `hook prerouting` chain, I think. But then the intemediate router might need to be used as the nexthop / gateway for the LAN subnet on both ISP routers, which could either be a tricky / impossible thing to do. (Well, or maybe you can do multi-layer DNAT / port forwarding, but that could be nasty and problematic too...if even feasible at all)